# show overlay on specific div and NOT on the whole viewport

Tags: css

I am working on an angular 5 app. I a, trying to show an overlay on each component ( Not on whole page) with some loading image.

Currently I am using the following CSS:

```css
 .overlay{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.5;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="overlay"> </div>
```

currently, overlay created on the whole view port.
How can we create overlay on an specific component OR div??

Comment: can you add more code please..your problem is unclear from above code

Comment: if you want to create it for a specific dive or component means, make that div or component `position: relative` and make the overlay `position: absolute`..but share the code also to help more

Comment: I will add more code in my question tonight to explain it better.